# Error while iterating over dictionary json data with swift: Could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: json, dictionary, swift

I figured out how to read a local json file in my project. But now I am having trouble iterating over it. Here is my raw json data:

```
{
    "locations": [
                  {
                  "title": "The Pump Room",
                  "place": "Bath",
                  "latitude": 51.38131,
                  "longitude": -2.35959,
                  "information": "The Pump Room Restaurant in Bath is one of the city’s most elegant places to enjoy stylish, Modern-British cuisine.",
                  "telephone": "+44 (0)1225 444477",
                  "url": "http://www.romanbaths.co.uk",
                  "visited" : true
                  },
                  {
                  "title": "The Eye",
                  "place": "London",
                  "latitude": 51.502866,
                  "longitude": -0.119483,
                  "information": "At 135m, the London Eye is the world’s largest cantilevered observation wheel. It was designed by Marks Barfield Architects and launched in 2000.",
                  "telephone": "+44 (0)8717 813000",
                  "url": "http://www.londoneye.com",
                  "visited" : false
                  },
                  {
                  "title": "Chalice Well",
                  "place": "Glastonbury",
                  "latitude": 51.143669,
                  "longitude": -2.706782,
                  "information": "Chalice Well is one of Britain's most ancient wells, nestling in the Vale of Avalon between the famous Glastonbury Tor and Chalice Hill.",
                  "telephone": "+44 (0)1458 831154",
                  "url": "http://www.chalicewell.org.uk",
                  "visited" : true
                  },
                  {
                  "title": "Tate Modern",
                  "place": "London",
                  "latitude": 51.507774,
                  "longitude": -0.099446,
                  "information": "Tate Modern is a modern art gallery located in London. It is Britain's national gallery of international modern art and forms part of the Tate group.",
                  "telephone": "+44 (0)20 7887 8888",
                  "url": "http://www.tate.org.uk",
                  "visited" : true
                  },
                  {
                  "title": "Eiffel Tower",
                  "place": "Paris",
                  "latitude": 48.858271,
                  "longitude": 2.294114,
                  "information": "The Eiffel Tower (French: La Tour Eiffel, is an iron lattice tower located on the Champ de Mars in Paris.",
                  "telephone": "+33 892 70 12 39",
                  "url": "http://www.tour-eiffel.fr",
                  "visited" : false
                  },
                  {
                  "title": "Parc Guell",
                  "place": "Barcelona",
                  "latitude": 41.414483,
                  "longitude": 2.152579,
                  "information": "Parc Guell is a garden complex with architectural elements situated on the hill of El Carmel in the Gràcia district of Barcelona.",
                  "telephone": "+34 902 20 03 02",
                  "url": "http://www.parkguell.es",
                  "visited" : false
                  }
                  ]
}
```

This is how I am reading and parsing it:

```
  func readLocationData() {

        let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
        let path = bundle.pathForResource("locations", ofType: "json")
        let content : NSString = NSString.stringWithContentsOfFile(path) as NSString

        let locationData:NSData = content.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        var error: NSError?

        var jsonDict:Dictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(locationData, options: nil, error: &error) as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

        if let locations : AnyObject = jsonDict["locations"] {
            if let information: String = locations["information"] {
               // I get error here: Could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments
            }
        }

    }
```

Now how do I get access to internal keys like `title`, `place` and `location`? Anything I try inside the loop gives a casting error like:

```
Could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at what types the different parts of the JSON are: `jsonDict` is a dictionary that has an array as its only value, and `jsonDict["locations"]` is an array of other dictionaries. You should be using `Dictionary<String, Any>` for `jsonDict` and then you'll have better luck later:

```
var jsonDict:Dictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(locationData, options: nil, error: &error) as Dictionary<String, Any>
let locations: NSArray? = jsonDict["locations"] as? NSArray

if locations {
    for location: AnyObject in locations! {
        if let information = location as? NSDictionary {
            println(information)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this gives me the error: `Could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments` on the `let locations...` line

Comment: Ok I think we are close. Now I get a runtime `thread exc` error: `fatal error: value failed to bridge from Objective-C type to a Swift type
(lldb)`

Comment: Perhaps it's a compiler / Swift bug -- switching to Foundation types fixes the problem -- see above

Comment: Nope - get error on this line: `let locations: NSArray? = jsonDict["locations"] as? NSArray`: `fatal error: value failed to bridge from Objective-C type to a Swift type`

Comment: That's odd - gets through the whole JSON file for me. Are you sure the JSON loads properly?

Comment: Yes - I double checked - it loads

Answer (score 0):

You have a dictionary with contains a single entry of "locations" which is an array of dictionaries.

Try this:

```
// I'm using NSDictionary since it is easier to work with when you don't know the object // // types  but you can convert it later with explicit data types

if let results = jsonDict["locations"] as NSDictionary[] {
    for item in results {
        var title = item["title"] as String
    }
}
```

Note: I haven't ran this code myself but you I think you should get the idea.

Comment: nope - I get error: ` Cannot convert the expression's type 'NSDictionary' to type 'NSDictionary'`

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you running this on a playground?

Comment: Also removed the second cast on results, not needed

Comment: with this solution, I get `fatal error: value failed to bridge from Objective-C type to a Swift type
(lldb) `

Comment: Add an "as String" or "as NSString" to the title